# Login Table Layout for MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, database-schema

I am new to MySQL databases and would like to get inputs from those who are familiar with it, while I work on a school project. I would like to create a login_table similar to

```
login_table 
---------------------
id PK 
emailAddress
password
firstName
lastName
telephone
address
```

I googled it and saw some examples, that only had {PK, userName, password}.

Would it be industry accepted to have all the information in one table or split the information? Do I need to encrypt the password prior to sending the value to the database or can be done in the database?

Comment: Having all information in one table seems okay to me as long as they are one-to-one relationship. As to password, you shouldn't store or transmit password (or encrypted password) at all. Instead, you need salted hash. Take a look at this answer: http://security.stackexchange.com/a/51983.

Comment: It's up to you, also you normally want to do a salted hash on the server side along with possibly using a key (personal preference) and concatenating that in the hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping a single table of user accounts is valid.  A common strategy for handling passwords is to require https on any form where a password is submitted (whether for account creation or for the login), and to either encrypt or hash the password in your app server before persisting to your database.

If you don't need the password for anything but verifying a login, then it's preferable to hash the password.  When storing the password, you could use, for example, `SHA2($server_key + $PK + $password)`.  You'd calculate and compare that hash each time from your retrieved data when a user was logging in.

If you need the passwords (e.g. if your app server proxies requests on the users' behalf to other systems), then encrypting the password for storage may be the more appropriate choice.

I'd advise against using the database to encrypt a password.  More than likely, you'd be transmitting that password in plaintext from your app server to the database server.  Additionally, you may want to migrate to a different database platform in the future, say, to some cloud storage solution.  If so, it's better to do tasks like parsing and encryption in your app server, and keep your database focused on persistence and retrieval.